# Diffing two files while ignoring any missed lines

Tags: python

I am diffing two unsorted files and my problem is the moment one of the files gets a line that is not present in the other file, the diff goes off. I want to write/print the line not present and then continue on.

```
import re
f1=open("file1","r")
f2=open("file2","r")
f=open("output","w")
test_lines=f1.readlines()
correct_lines=f2.readlines()

for test, correct in zip(sorted(test_lines), sorted(correct_lines)):
    if test.strip().split("(")[0].replace(" ","").strip() != correct.strip().split("(")[0].replace(" ","").strip() and test!="\n":
        print "Oh no! Expected %r; got %r." % (correct, test)
    else:
        towrite=correct + test
        f.write(towrite)

else:
    len_diff = len(test_lines) - len(correct_lines)
    if len_diff > 0:
        print "Test file had too much data."
    elif len_diff < 0:
        print "Test file had too little data."
    else:
        print "Everything was correct!"
```

sample input

file1

```
 jack
tom
apple
orange
```

file2

```
jack
apple
ape
 mike
```

It will print 
Oh no! expected apple got ape
and then everything is a fail

Comment: Can you add an example input data?

Comment: Perhaps [difflib could help You](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) ? I think difflib.context_diff() would suit Your needs, basing on current problem description.

Comment: Thanks will try difflib

Comment: That is the output i get when i run your program with given inputs:

    Oh no! Expected ' mike\n'; got 'apple\n'.
    Oh no! Expected 'ape\n'; got 'jack\n'.
    Oh no! Expected 'apple\n'; got 'orange\n'.
    Oh no! Expected 'jack\n'; got 'tom\n'.
    Everything was correct!

Comment: Apple is present in both files, i don't want a line by line comparision, i want it to only show missing tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comments you don't want line by line comparison. I think Python's `set` is best suited for your case. Here is a snippet:

```
import re
f1=open("file1","r")
f2=open("file2","r")
f=open("output","w")
test_lines=f1.readlines()
correct_lines=f2.readlines()

test_lines = set([l.strip().split("(")[0].replace(" ","").strip() for l in test_lines])
correct_lines = set([l.strip().split("(")[0].replace(" ","").strip() for l in correct_lines])

print "Expected: ", correct_lines-test_lines    
print "Got: ", test_lines-correct_lines
```

Output:

```
Expected:  set(['mike', 'ape'])
Got:  set(['orange', 'tom'])
```